# Comparison test proof of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I want to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3^n+4^n}{3^n+5^n}$ converges. To do this, I said that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3^n+4^n}{3^n+5^n}<3\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{4}{5})^n$, which indeed converges. Hence by the comparison test, the series we are given converges. Is this valid?

Comment: you need to explain if it is valid or not. What is the reasoning there? The inequality is true? Can you prove it?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\frac{3^n+4^n}{3^n+5^n} \le \frac{3^n+4^n}{5^n} = \left(\frac 35 \right)^n + \left(\frac 45 \right)^n \le 2\left(\frac 45 \right)^n $$

Comment: Unless I have misinterpreted the query, your response is *off topic*.  See my comments - does your analysis dovetail with the Limit Comparison Test?

Comment: @user2661923 Why *Limit* Comparison Test? I think the asker is trying to do [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test)

Comment: **Yes, you're right**.  I googled Wikipedia Comparison Test, and fell into the Limit Comparison Test article, not realizing that there was a separate test that also had the adjective *Comparison*.  I completely agree with you.